# Saving continuosly generated data from browser to file

Tags: javascript, webrtc

My JS webapp running in browser is receiving data via webrtc data channel.

Now I need save received data to file. I can receive data into blob and then save to file, but I need to save data continuously without have all data in memory.

For example my application is receiving 5 GB of data in small chunks and it is IMHO not good practice to link all chunks in memory into one huge blob and than save it to file.

I wish it worked the same way how the standard downloading works. Any idea?

Comment: How are you saving the blob as a file?

Comment: You could send the datachunks down through a websocket using Json. Then on the websocketserver, parse the JSon and push it to a file.

Comment: I'm saving blob as file using var url = window.URL.createObjectURL(dataBlob); and then create Link with url and user can click on it and save data to file.

Comment: Have a look at https://www.webrtc-experiment.com/RecordRTC/

Comment: @user2106769 Did you find a solution?

Comment: @Hossein Ganjyar> Nope, but maybe this module can do it - https://www.npmjs.com/package/streamsaver

Comment: @user2106769, please see my question. streamsaver have a problem.
   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42339969/javascript-download-continuously-data?noredirect=1#comment71835108_42339969

Answer (score 0):

You will have to download each blob(you can look at [RecordRTC](https://github.com/muaz-khan/WebRTC-Experiment/tree/master/RecordRTC)) and then merge them together after you download them.

Another option would be sending the data actively through a websocket and merging it back together once it hits the WebSocketServer.

Comment: Yes, but when I was downloading 2 GB file this way, I would need to have 2GB in RAM in merged blob and than save. But when you download 2GB file in standard way (download link), the file is written to disk part by part, so the browser will not allocate 2GB in RAM, and this is the beahavior I need. Any suggestions? Sending received data to the server and then redownload merged file back again is not an option, because it generates a lot of server traffic what I want to avoid by WEBRTC.

Comment: douplicate:    
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42066537/javascript-download-stream-data