# Javascript - Download stream data

Tags: javascript, node.js, stream

I get data(2GB) from server(NodeJS) by stream method and now I want download this data on browser(client), but recieved data are increasing and use a lot memory(RAM) but I don't want this. In other word I want save this data on hard drive no in my browser(RAM).

### app.js

```
var http = require('http');
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var server = http.Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(server);

io.on('connection', function (socket) {
    console.log('Connection is ready!')
    socket.on('get_records', function (data) {
    var connection = new sql.Connection(config, function (err) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err.message);
        }

        var request = new sql.Request(connection);
        request.stream = true;

        request.query("Select * from my_table"); //2GB data
        // ... error checks
        request.on('recordset', function (recordset) {
            // Emitted once for each recordset in a query
        });

        request.on('row', function (message) {
            // Emitted for each row in a recordset
            socket.emit('recieve_records', message); //send record by record to client
        });

        request.on('error', function (err) {
            console.log(err.message);
        });

        request.on('done', function (returnValue) {
            // Always emitted as the last one
        });
    });
});
```

### client.js

```
socket.on('recieve_records', function (data) {
    email.push(data);
});
```

Comment: you can use Blob API

Comment: @siam please get sample