# Javascript - Download continuously data

Tags: javascript, stream, streaming, download

I have receiving data from server(10,000,000 records) continuously, no all of them in one place.(using ***socket.io.js***)
I want download this data continuously by create Csv/Json file and retain data into **HardDisk** no **Ram** from first downloading, because size of all of records is **~2GB** and I don't wish involved *memory*.

**Notice**:

1. I used of [*StreamSaver.js*](https://github.com/jimmywarting/StreamSaver.js?utm_source=recordnotfound.com) already, but it had many problem (not suport firefox, [*error in downloading*](https://github.com/jimmywarting/StreamSaver.js/issues/45)).
2. Using 100 users from this app and my server has limitation in memeory/cpu.

### client.js

```
socket.on('receive_records', function (data) {
    //Receive data 
});
```

Comment: Why don't you create the file on the server side and pass it to the client as a normal file download, rather then passing the data to the client and making it create the file from that?

Comment: @George, because I have limitation in server's memory/cpu and using 100 users from this app.

Comment: Streaming 2GB of data is not very optimal. Is the file unique for each user? If not, or if groups of users can see the same file, you would probably be better of with some sort of caching and http delivery system.

Comment: @EmilS.Jørgensen, yes uniqe for each user.
Why not very optimal?

Comment: Even if you can ignore the overhead by using websockets, your data isn't as compressed as they could be in a file (think gzip for instance). Furthermore they would take computation power both on your server for sending **and** on the users machine for "building" the file from the stream. And finally, if the data isn't doing anything in the browser but merely downloading, why not allow the browsers build-in download manager take care of it via an http transfer?